# Change script tag with ajax, why still working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi my question is about how a problem was solved... a friend has html a code like:

```
<div id="result">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectColor(value){
            return "#319336";
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

and with a jQuery .load() call in result calls a PHP file with a function that sends a JavaScript function like this

```
<?php
    function returnFuntion(){
        return '<script type="text/javascript">
            function selectColor(value){
                switch(value){
                    case "a":
                        return "#000000";
                        break;
                    case "b":
                        return "#FFFFFF";
                        break;
                    default:
                        return "#319336";
                }
        }</script>';
    }
?>
```

I don't know how this is working, but works in all browsers, my friend says "it works don't worry". What happens? Why JavaScript recognizes the new code and not the old? Is that a correct way to do it? The original problem was the JavaScript function return must change with MySQL values obtained from PHP.

Comment: I think load() adds the function latter in page then initial definition. So it takes the last definition for each call.

Comment: What exactly is the first function supposed to do? Why does it accept a parameter `value` that is not used? Why abstract a simple string into a function?

Comment: @migg is part of another funtion who's calling selectColor and send a value representing the color, but the value from DB is not obtained yet, so default value is returned. in a mysql database is written the relation color-value, but that relation is in another relation like user-[color-value] if the user isn't selected yet the data of relation color-value is not set and the funtion must be declared to prevent errors.

Comment: So then your answer to why it works is given by @Sushanth, it works because the later function definition overrides the first one. If there is a correct way to do it is more a philosophical question, your solution is not wrong at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are function declarations and the parser always reads these declarations before any code is read.

So the first function is simply overridden when the second is defined

```
  function a(){

        alert('Hello');
    }

    function a(){

       alert('Second Function !!');
    }

    a(); // Call--
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/XzfGt/)

Comment: I doubt if your answer is relevant to what he asked. What you answered is about ovrriding functions. He has no function which being overridden. He asked the first one doesnt work but the second one works. He wants to know why. Sorry if i failed to understand the question.

Comment: thanks for answer, well... in fact that explains how it was possible to works, I'm sorry maybe bad explanation, but i didnt know override was the name of what my friend was doing, i dont know if overriding functions is fine but now I know how was that working.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally both the script should work perfectly but the first one is really not a good way of writing javascript inside a div. If its not working it maybe because the function is called before it is even loaded. The second one is fine, because php is formatting that javascript and its ready to be printed somewhere in your page. The key thing to remember is first the function should be loaded/printed and then it should be called to avoid any error.

Answer (score 0):

@luismy, you are always better off exchanging data, not scripts, between server and client. I am just curious why don't you implement UI logic on the client side, and application logic on the server? Especially for this example, it just does not make sense to even make an XHR call.

Comment: it is for the table structure in mysql, it is a relation related to an item like item->{color->value} in order to have the relation color-value, I need the user select item to select what relation to call.

Comment: After select the "item" I made an ajax call to get the relation with color and value, that relation is defined in the js, the example code I wrote, it's that, an example the real code works with other values and does other things to create the js function, but I cant show the real code and I didn't know the javascript functions can be overwritten. I hope that responds your question @mvbl.

Comment: Alright, what I am saying is that for each request with color, you get a JSON with options, e.g. `{ 'a': '#000000', 'b': '#ffffff', 'default': '#319336' }` and on the client side you just deal with data. Basically exchanging scripts is not a great idea, but exchanging data is. Your controllers in pure form should be returning data, not inline script tags.

Comment: Yes @mvbl fst, thank you for your answer, I see that was not the right way to do it, but that was a solution and works, in the future i wont do a thing like that, that code was made some time ago but I still asking me how was working, you answer what was the right way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading JavaScript, use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Have the php code just return the content just like you were writing an external file. Make sure to set the content type also.